# Multiple monitors using Docking Station

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I want to buy a laptop that has both HDMI and VGA. Since I can't connect two external monitors at the same time (to have 3 displays in total), I'm thinking about buying a **docking station** ([this one](http://www.kensington.com/kensington/us/us/p/2915/K33970US/usb-3-0-docking-station-with-dvi-hdmi-vga-video-%28sd3000v%29.aspx) or similar).

**Has someone tested having 3 displays (or more) connected at the same time?**

For example, I'd like to know if I can have an external monitor plugged in through VGA (directly to the laptop) and one more using HDMI/DVI (plus the laptop display itself, being 3 displays in total).

Comment: This can be only an assumption whether it will work or not without exactly to know all details about your hardware in my humble opinion, I would ask the vendor before I buy in your stead ...

Answer (score 1):

Multimonitor support is completely dependent on the operating system and drivers in use. Having said that, your desired setup is likely to work barring driver issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question: the laptop I'm planning to buy has a NVIDIA 740M. According to http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-740M.89900.0.html ... "This includes support for up to 4 active displays". Does it means I'll be able to connect one monitor through HDMI and another one through VGA, directly to the laptop?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on how the system integrator wired it up.